# creating small MS Access db where have same customer/company operating in multiple states

Tags: ms-access

want to create simple access db that will allow entry of customers that do business  in multiple states. So be able to create company table with things like company name,email, state but be able to put in multiple states if that company works out of more then one. Say company a is out of Florida, company b is in new york, florida,texas, company c is arizona and florida.  once all tables created would then want to be able to query all companies operating in a given state and get list of the companies. so if i queried companies operating in florida, i would get companies a, b and c back in this example.  So how best to create the underlying tables and joins/relationships in access to make this work?  any example access dbs i could download and use as template would help or a good explaination of how best to setup the needed tables (companies, states,etc) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to create that main table tblCustomers.

And then create a child table called tblAddress.

In the child table, you can thus enter the address/state/phone number of the company address(s) you have. So you might have one, or 5 such different addresses.

To edit this setup, you thus create a main form with company info etc. You then build a sub form that allows edit of the address.

Then with main form in design mode, simply drop in the form from the nave pane. If you setup the revelations between the tables correctly before doing this, then Access will automatic link up the address for the given company.

So you don’t need a multiple states table, but simply a table that represents the whole address. You as noted might want to include the email, phone number. Thus you can easy enter a company, and then enter address (with state) along with email or phone number for as many locations as you please.

So far, this relation as outlined only requires two tables. The main table, and the table of addresses.